# Ansible how to create list of dictionary keys

Tags: dictionary, variables, ansible

I am probably missing something simple. I have the dictionary in *vars.yml*

```yaml
    deploy_env:
      dev:
        schemas:
          year1:
            - main
            - custom
          year2:
            - main
            - custom
            - security
          year3:
            - main
            - custom
```

Then in my *playbook.yml*, I have something like

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        years: "{{ deploy_env.dev.schemas }}"
    
    - name: Create schemas
      shell: "mysql ....params go here... {{ item }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ years }}"
```

The above works fine if schemas in *vars.yml* were a simple list ie:

```yaml
    deploy_env:
      dev:
        schemas:
          - year1
          - year2
          - year3
```

But as soon as I add additional items under each year (making this a dictionary(?) I start getting errors on the line:

```yaml
       - "{{ years }}
```

I basically want to populate *{{ years }}* with *year1*,*year2*,*year3* values for this task.

I've looked at many examples but everything I looked at was soo complex and it was about how to create dictionaries which is not helpful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is possible to create a list of the dictionary's keys. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        years: "{{ deploy_env.dev.schemas.keys()|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ years }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    item: year1
    item: year2
    item: year3
```

---

**List vs Dictionary**

Quoting from the question:

> *"... I add additional items under each year (making this a dictionary(?) ..."*

Adding items doesn't change a list to a dictionary. An item of a list is introduced by a dash `-` in [YAML](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/YAMLSyntax.html).

Example of a list:

```yaml
    schemas:
      - year1
      - year2
      - year3
```

Example of a list of hashes with single lists:

```yaml
    schemas:
      - year1:
          - main
          - custom
      - year2:
          - main
          - custom
          - security
      - year3:
          - main
          - custom
```

Example of a dictionary:

```yaml
    schemas:
      year1:
        - main
        - custom
      year2:
        - main
        - custom
        - security
      year3:
        - main
        - custom
```

---

Notes:

- Some [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#using-filters-to-manipulate-data) convert a dictionary when used as an argument where a list is expected, to the list of its keys. For example, the filter [difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) manipulates lists

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ deploy_env.dev.schemas|difference(['year2']) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - year1
  - year3
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    deploy_env:
      dev:
        schemas:
          year1: [main, custom]
          year2: [main, custom, security]
          year3: [main, custom]

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        years: "{{ deploy_env.dev.schemas.keys()|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ years }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ deploy_env.dev.schemas|difference(['year2']) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your list of lists is not. It is a list of dictionaries w/ a single key whose value is a list. ie in JSON {"schemas": [{"year1": ["main", "custom"]}, {"year2": ["main", "custom", "security"]}, {"year3": ["main", "custom"]}]} - this shows the dicts w/ {} and lists with [] explicitly.

Comment: Right. This is accurate. Thank you.